# Django не подключаются templates

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Версия Django - 1.8.
Не подключаются templates через `settings.py`, в учебнике сказано использовать следующий код: `TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`, но он является устаревшим(т.е. используется для старых версий), поэтому я использовал следующее:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Добавил папку `templates`, в которую включил `admin` и все содержимое из `django/contrib/admin/template`
Вот структура проекта:
[image: структура проекта]
[image: дополнение]

Comment: С какой целью вы поместили файлы с расширением `.py` в директорию с шаблонами ?

Comment: @matz она не в директории с шаблонами, внимательно следите за стрелочкой у папки:)

Comment: Кто она ? Я про тот же `wsgi.py`. Судя по стрелочкам, файл находится в директории с шаблонами.

Comment: @matz дополнил вопрос для ясности

Comment: Лучше использовать вывод утилиты `tree` для Unix-подобных ОС.
Директория с шаблонами располагается в `BASE_DIR`.
Судя по всему, вам нужно переместить ваши шаблоны директорией выше, т.е. наверх (из addressbook).

Comment: Делал подобное, не помогло.

Comment: А вывод в логах какой ? Там будет выведена информация об ошибке

Comment: Там нет ошибки, даже если удалить папку templates

Comment: Создайте вьюху, шаблон и посмотрите лог ошибки в браузере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно было вынести папку `templates` за пределы `addressbook`

Comment: Делал подобное, не помогло (c)

Comment: угу, django глючил, в принципе, можешь написать ответ, я его поставлю как правильный

Comment: нет, спаибо :) Проблема решена и хорошо :)))